# Using Multiple Configuration Files in Flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, configuration-files

Right now I am using this to load my configurations for my app,

```
await GlobalConfiguration().loadFromAsset("app_settings");
...
GlobalConfiguration().getString("app-setting-1");
GlobalConfiguration().getString("app-setting-2");
...
```

This is working great so far.

But now my configuration file has grown a bit.
And I would like to split the configuration file in multiple parts.

For example:

```
app_settings_general
app_settings_reports
app_settings_payments
```

each of these files will then hold parameters for different aspects of the app.

This to allow management of the parameters to be easier to handle,
and replacements or changes to be made to one configuration file, without needing to open or care about the other ones.

I have by example different aspect of the app,
**payment module configuration**
**report configuration**
**order module configuration**
and so on

I have look into different pages but all talk about using different configuration files for different environments, not about using multiple configuration files in the same app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are sure that the keys are unique across all the config files, then you can just use

```
await GlobalConfiguration().loadFromAsset("app_settings_general");
await GlobalConfiguration().loadFromAsset("app_settings_report");
```

which will load all the configurations in both files to single variable only.

**Otherwise: (if files have duplicate keys)**

We can write our own helper classes. You can refer following sample.

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

class AppConfiguration {
  AppConfiguration._internal();

  static final _globConfig = "globConfig";

  static final _singleton = AppConfiguration._internal();

  factory AppConfiguration() {
    return _singleton;
  }

  final _configs = Map<String, dynamic>();

  Future<AppConfiguration> loadConfigs(String name,
      {String category}) async {
    final configJsonString =
    await rootBundle.loadString("assets/configs/$name");

    Map<String, dynamic> configJson = json.decode(configJsonString);

    if (category == null || category.isEmpty) category = _globConfig;

    if (_configs[category] == null) _configs[category] = Map<String, dynamic>();

    _configs[category].addAll(configJson);

    return _singleton;
  }

  T getConfig<T>(String key, {String category}) {
    if (category == null || category.isEmpty) category = _globConfig;
    return _configs[category][key] as T;
  }
}
```

**Usage:**

1. Place all the json config files to "assets/configs/" folder
2. Specify the config folder in `pubspec.yaml`

```
flutter:
 assets:
  - assets/configs/
```

3. To load the configuration on app start

```
void main() async{
  await AppConfiguration().loadConfigs("app_settings_general", category: "general");
  await AppConfiguration().loadConfigs("app_settings_report", category: "report");
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

4. To access config value inside app

```
AppConfiguration().getConfig("key1", category: "general");
AppConfiguration().getConfig<String>("key2", category: "report");
```

Comment: Thank you this is really helpfull, i did not know that i could have multiple files and load them all in global config

Comment: You can find official docs here.  https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/flavors